# Can't configure HTTP.SYS to allow SSL traffic (netsh.exe)

Tags: wcf, certificate, netsh

I’m running self-hosting service and when I try to configure HTTP.SYS to allow SSL traffic:

```
Netsh http add sslcert 0.0.0.0:8000 
                       ba616b762ba67f30d62a94c59febf34bbf3089a9 
                      {4dc3e181-e14b-4a21-b022-59fc669b0914}

where 'ba...' string is thumbprint of a installed certificate 
and '{4dc3e…}' is just some random number ( which I assume will be used
as an application identifier )
```

I get error *“SSL Certificate add failed, Error:1312. A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated”* . Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you find the solution to this, I'm having the exact same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the format is not

```
httpcfg set ssl /i 10.0.0.1:80 /h 2c8bfddf59a4a51a2a5b6186c22473108295624d /g "{2bb50d9c-7f6a-4d6f-873d-5aee7fb43290}"
```

Comment: you're using httpcfg, while I used netsh, so I'm not quite sure what your point is. Namely, as far as I know, netsh is replacement for httpcfg on newer windows systems ( I'm using Windows 7 )

Comment: oh sorry, hadn't catched that. However, the format is still something like: add sslcert ipport=1.1.1.1:443 certhash=0102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F1011121314 appid={00112233-4455-6677-8899-AABBCCDDEEFF}. And are you sure about the ip address 0.0.0.0? seems odd.

Comment: "However, the format is still something like:..." Both formats produce the same error "And are you sure about the ip address 0.0.0.0? seems odd." 0.0.0.0 indicates all IP addresses

Comment: That seems to be a known issue, see this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/981506/en

Comment: uhm, I've installed the hotfix and I still get the same error

Comment: hopefully someone's got a solution, else I'm f*****. anyways, thanx for your help

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem when my cert is stored in the "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" store .

To workaround:

1. In CertManager, Drag the cert into "Personal" store.
2. Then run your command (httpcfg or "NetSh httpadd sslcert ..." on newer windows)
3. Then drag the cert back to "Trusted Root Certification Authorities".

Also when, your cert is the in the "Personal" store, you change which user accounts can use the cert by choosing: "More Actions...All Tasks...Manage Private Keys". You don't get this menu in the "Trusted Root Certificaotin Authorities" store.